# My Drop Down Menu is being pushed down - can't find class that's doing it

Tags: html, css

I'm having a issue with my drop-down menu being pushed down so much. The CSS is pretty dense and I've tried locating the culprit class but with so many @media queries, I'm not entirely sure what's causing it. It appears to be a padding issue as none of the nav drop elements having margin specs. Anyone wanna take a look?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kedGi.png)

And here are all the CSS:

```css
#nav ul li {
 font-size: 20px;
 line-height: 20px;
 font-weight: 300;
 text-transform: capitalize;
 margin: 0 0 3px;
 position: relative;
}

#nav ul li:hover > a {
 color: #6c8845;
}

#nav ul li:hover .drop {
 display: block;
}

#nav ul a {
 color: #fff;
 display: block;
 padding: 11px 26px;
}

#nav .drop {
 display: none;
}

#nav .drop ul {
 background: #272526;
}

#nav .drop ul li {
 margin: 0 0 -3px;
}

#nav .drop ul a {
 padding: 14px;
 padding-left: 61px;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) and (min-width: 1024px)
#nav .drop {
  -webkit-transition: visibility .3s ease-in-out, opacity .3s ease-in-out;
  transition: visibility .3s ease-in-out, opacity .3s ease-in-out;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 100%;
  width: 200px;
  z-index: 9;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 50px 0 0;
 }

 .fixed-position #nav .drop {
  padding: 32px 0 0;
 }

 #nav .drop ul {
  background: #322f31;
 }

 #nav .drop ul li {
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
 }

 #nav .drop ul a {
  color: #fff;
  padding: 18px;
  position: relative;
 }

 #nav .drop ul a:hover {
  background: #6c8845;
  color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 11px 14px -8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .4) inset;
 }

 #nav .drop ul a:hover:before {
  opacity: 1;
 }

 #nav .drop ul a:before {
  -webkit-transition: opacity .3s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity .3s ease-in-out;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  border-bottom: 9.5px solid transparent;
  border-left: 9px solid #c4c9ce;
  border-top: 9.5px solid transparent;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  opacity: 0;
 }
```

Comment: Could you please post the HTML for the navigation as well?

Comment: need your html mate

Comment: Just a guess until we see HTML, but in `#nav drop` you've got `top: 100%;`, which would push the element to the bottom of the nearest relative or absolute positioned ancestor element.